# CSS Divs postions

Tags: css, sass

Consider following illustration:
[image]

DIV ONE occupies entire screen, and on button press it is shrinked to 50% and DIV TWO occupies right 50% space.

How can I achieve this using css or scss?

Comment: Achieve the click effect or the layout ?

Comment: Can you post some HTML or CSS to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you, it's easy to achieve this in Javascript:

Your button:

```
<button onclick="yourFunction()">Button</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function yourFunction(){
    document.getElementById('divOne').style.width = "50%";
}
```